# How many seconds it will take to activate resurrect after a finishing a resurrect in Temple run?

Tags: ios, temple-run

In Temple Run I have activated resurrect, this power is active for me 30 seconds. After 30 seconds it is deactivated. Now I want to again activate the resurrect power but it will activate after a certain number of seconds. My Question is after how many seconds we can able to activate the resurrect power ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wings last for 30 seconds and you can activate them after they run out after **20 seconds**. There is a distinct sound that signals this.